# VB.Net Return IPv4 Address

Tags: vb.net, networking, ip, ipv4

How can I return the IPv4 address in VB.Net?

eg. 192.168.1.5

Comment: Do you want the IP address of a given hostname?  Or the IP address of a incoming request?  Or the IP address of the local machine (which could have multiple addresses)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim myClientMachineAddressList As IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
Dim myClientMachineIP As String = myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList(0).ToString()
```

edit:

then you can use [IPAddress.AddressFamily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily(VS.80).aspx) to find out IP familly type.

Comment: Will return IPv6 if it's there (I think)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```
Public Function GetIpV4() As String

  Dim myHost As String = Dns.GetHostName
  Dim ipEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost)
  Dim ip As String = ""

  For Each tmpIpAddress As IPAddress In ipEntry.AddressList
     If tmpIpAddress.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
        Dim ipAddress As String = tmpIpAddress.ToString
        ip = ipAddress
        exit for
     End If
  Next

  If ip = "" Then
     Throw New Exception("No 10. IP found!")
  End If

  Return ip

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Best I can do is that, will return only IPv4 address 
just using array functions and lambda expressions, very clean :

```
Public Function GetHostEntryIPv4(ByVal addr As String) As IPHostEntry

    Dim ipHostInfo As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr)

    If Not IsNothing(ipHostInfo) Then
        ipHostInfo.AddressList = Array.FindAll(ipHostInfo.AddressList, Function(n As IPAddress) n.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    End If

    GetHostEntryIPv4 = ipHostInfo

End Function
```